# make a POST api call in express router with request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httprequest

I am trying to make a POST request that returns data to me. I then want to push this data to my route to be added to my index route. heres my API call:

```
https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search 

{
  "api_key" : "my API key",
  "fields" : [ "name", "description", "location", "contact", "website_url", "menu_url", "open_hours" ],
  "venue_queries" : [
    {
        "categories" : "restaurant",
        "location" : {
        "geo" : {
          "$in_lat_lng_radius" : [44.0521, -123.116207, 6000]
        }
      },
      "delivery" : {
        "will_deliver" : true
      }

    }
  ]
}
```

If I make this request in postman then I get the data I would expect.

I would like to use request to make this api call. I have tried like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

var params = {
  "api_key" : "myApiKey",
  "fields" : [ "name", "description", "location", "contact", "website_url", "menu_url", "open_hours" ],
  "venue_queries" : [
    {
        "categories" : "restaurant",
        "location" : {
        "geo" : {
          "$in_lat_lng_radius" : [44.0521, -123.116207, 6000]
        }
      },
      "delivery" : {
        "will_deliver" : true
      }

    }
  ]
}

request.post({url:'https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search', params}, function(err,httpResponse,body){
    var resBody = JSON.parse(body)
    console.log(resBody);
})

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Just to console.log the results but I get the error:

```
{ status: 'error',
  http_status: 400,
  error: 'Request body is not a valid JSON object.' }
```

Is this because of the way I'm passing in my params? How can I send this data to my '/' route? can I just save it to a variable then pass it in? Or is there a better pattern for this?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve here. You do a `post` request and you only define a `get` route. Where is the route that handles the `post` request? What data you expect the `resBody` to have?

Comment: I only see a `GET` route defined, and I don't see if you've added a body parser to your Express app that allows it to handle incoming JSON requests. Have you added `"body-parser"`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your `params` as the `body`of the request, and you should also probably set the content type to JSON:

```
request.post({
    url:'https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search', 
    body:params,
    json: true
}, function(err, response, body){
    console.log(body);
})
```

Comment: This gives me an error stack that I don't understand:
yntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request._callback (/Users/Zach/foodopennow/routes/index.js:29:24)
    at Request.self.callback

Comment: This is probably caused by trying to call `JSON.parse` on the response body. Try the updated version above.